# Как добавить кнопки undo и redo на панель инструментов android studio

Tags: android-studio

Как добавить кнопки undo и redo на панель инструментов android studio
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Сама панель инструментов есть?

Comment: Да, сама панель есть

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Они там по умолчанию есть, но если вдруг кто-то убрал, то

Если отсутствует Панель иструментов:

- Меню View, поставить галочку у Toolbar.

Если Панель инструментов присутствует, но нет кнопок:

- Меню File - Settings - Appearance and Behaviour - Menus and Toolbars, кнопка Restore All Defaults. Вернется исходное состояние и положение всех кнопок.

Если исходное положение возрвращать не требуется (были другие кастомные настройки и их не хочется терять), то выбрать в списке Main Toolbar, нажать на Add After..., в открывшемся окне выбрать All Actions - Main Menu - Edit. Там будут обе кнопки. Добавить их по очереди и разместить в нужном месте используя Move Up и Move Down.

Comment: При Restore All Defaults они все равно не появляються в toolbare

Comment: Я дополнил как можно вручную добавить.

Comment: Да, спасибо, вручную все получилось